# UIScrollview overlapping mainview content

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, subview, uiscrollviewdelegate, layoutsubviews

Currently, I have this feature in my app where I implemented a UIScrollview that is pretty thin in height but long in width...

[image: Hourly Forecast]

As you can see, the UIScrollView is OVERLAPPING the backgroundview... Not that white background is a UIView to which I added the UIScrollView as a SUBVIEW.

Question is, how is the UIScrollView overlapping the black background content when it's just added to the subview?

Here is my init method for the UIScrollView..

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 70);
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480, 70);
    self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.bounces = NO;
}
```

And here is how I added the UIScrollView to the UIView (whitebackground view) whose name is ForecastView:

```
_hourlyForecast = [[hourlyForecastScrollView alloc] init:_city state:_state icons:_icons times:_times temps:_temps];
_hourlyForecast.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
_hourlyForecast.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, self.ForecastView.bounds.size.width, 70);
[_ForecastView addSubview:_hourlyForecast];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a view will not clip it's subviews. To enable clipping, set the UIView [clipsToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) property, or set it in Interface Builder

[image]

(credit to [Mugunth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90165/mugunth) for the image)